# Is there any way to run code on the client in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

As the title says, how would I go about doing this? I want to check a value stored in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible and has nothing to do with ASP .NET. The browser is responsible for rendering the page to the client, and browsers, for obvious reasons (security), don't have access to the user's file system. The only thing a browser can do, is read cookies (essentially text files) sent to the user from the same domain the website belongs to.

HTML5 has a new feature called [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) but you still won't be able to access *ANY* file on the user's computer.

Comment: There was a time when you could write a control in C# that runs on the client, but hosted inside an ASP.Net webpage as a kind of ActiveX control, but it was a massive security issue and only worked on IE. Long story short, if you want to read a file on the local PC, you have to ask the user to upload it to your server, the alternative is letting your webpage have access to all files on the local machine which is a big horrible problem, a malicious website processing your registry file or your .passwd file for example.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript with ASP.Net applications can work quite well, I've done it for a couple of sites I've done.  If you just want to run some code on the client when a checkbox is ticked for instance, try this...

replace the myFunction() portion out with whatever client side code you want to write.

If you unfamiliar with Javascript as a language, check this out... http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using ActiveX control or SilverLight

Answer (score 0):

Some are saying it's not possible, and that is true for the Internet.  However, I have done this before on an Intranet system.  The server knew the users computer name and could access a local configuration file, no ActiveX, no Silverlight.